# How to set position of bootstrap slider images to center?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want in my bootstrap slider the images placed in center of page such as this image[image]:

In this slider two section must be empty   :

> right and left section

```
<!--Slider-->
<div class="row">

    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->

        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item">
                <img src="images/4172_780x354_hp_mysterious_v1.jpg" />
                <div class="container">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="images/4181_780x354_hp_kitchen_v1.jpg" />
                <div class="container">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="images/4182_780x354_hp_sport-wear_v1.jpg" />
                <div class="container">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I use this codes but images placed in right of page.

> My website direction is right to left

Comment: Could you give website link?

Comment: My website Link : http://hmahdavi.zgig.ir/%D9%86%D9%85%D9%88%D9%86%D9%87%20%DA%A9%D8%A7%D8%B102/bamilo_Demo/Index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
.carousel-inner img {
  margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you salma sultana .The short and right answer